# Categorise data: if value is x then y

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I have a column of values like this in a dataframe:

```
   0

0   1.047297

1   1.038211

2   1.035080

3   1.005149
```

and I would like to create a new column where if the value in one 'cell' of the column is greater than `x` then it will return `1` and if not, then `0`.

Essentially I'm trying to mimic an excel function: `if(cell > x,1,0)`

It's a blindingly simple task, but I just can't find a simple answer - help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
df = # your data frame
df['newcolumn'] = np.where(df['cell'] > x, 1, 0)
```

See [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) docs for more details.